# Change browser width setting for when the mobile menu appears in the Wordpress twenty seventeen theme

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I need to to have the mobile menu appear at a 750px width in Twenty Seventeen.

Answer (score -1):

Just apply css media query to your style. just like this.

Reference link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 751px) {
  .menu { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .menu { display: block; }
}
```